# Can't boot up Ubuntu 13.04 from a bootable USB, computer starts Windows 7

Tags: 13.04, live-usb, windows-7

I had downloaded the Ubuntu 13.04 ISO and made it bootable on a USB, but when I pressed <kbd>F12</kbd> nothing happened and my computer just started Windows 7 regularly.

How do I get Ubuntu to boot up?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

As soon as you power on the computer, start pressing each of the following keys about 2-3 times per second.  Do this repeatedly with each key, so for example boot up once and press F2 about 2-3 times per second until you get to Windows boot or a menu that you can boot into the USB.  If F2 doesn't work, try again with F4.  If none of those work, please edit question and include all the information that displays on your screen when you boot, before you get to Windows.

F2, F4, F10, F12, Esc (escape)